# How to avoid nested branches caused by source code dependency hierarchy

Tags: tfs, branch, dependency-management

We are using TFS 2010, and we have some very annoying trouble with our dependency/branch management.

At first glance, our problem is quite common. We have `AppServer`, `WebClient` and `WinClient`. Both `WebClient` and `WinClient` depend on `AppServer`. There are two additional limitations:

1. we prefer to include specific version of used dependency
2. we prefer to include source code and not binaries, because it's easier to implement and test `AppServer` changes coming from specific origin, for example, `WinClient`.

We choose following folder structure:

```
\
|-AppServer (1)
|-WebClient
    |-Dependencies
        |-AppServer (2)
    |-Sources
|-WinClient
    |-Dependencies
        |-AppServer (3)
    |-Sources
```

`AppServer`s `(2)` and `(3)` are branches (as first-class branch) of `AppServer (1)`. It all works pretty well and matches our development scenario.

Now, there comes a trouble. Suppose we want to implement "branch-per-release" pattern on `WebClient`, which implies branching whole `WebClient` hierarchy into another place. We **can't** do that because TFS2010 does not allow nested first class branches.

To add to the challenge, we envision branch hierarchy (only for `WebClient`, and we have several other dependent and dependency projects) to be something like this:

```
WebClient
    |-Client1
    |    |-feature-1
    |    |-feature-2
    |    |-v1 Release
    |    |   |-v1 hotfix1
    |    |   |-v1 hotfix2
    |    |-v2 Release
    |        |-v1 hotfix1
    |        |-v1 hotfix2
    |
    |-Client2
         |-feature-1
         |-feature-2
         |-v1 Release
         |   |-v1 hotfix1
         |   |-v1 hotfix2
         |-v2 Release
             |-v1 hotfix1
             |-v1 hotfix2
```

What are our options? I can think of several:

1. Convert first-class branches to folders. That will allow us to nest branches, but we will lose tracking and visualization, which I don't like.
2. We can somehow restructure our code with regards to dependencies. But I tried to think of it for some time and still don't see the answer.
3. We can switch from code dependencies to binary dependencies, but that will slow our development.

Is there any solution I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts:

1) You could keep your AppServer Branches separate and un-nested from your WebClients and just use the Workspace Mapping functionality in TFS to emulate something like what you've defined via branching AppServer into the Client branches. This would allow a dev to select the AppServer branch they want and nest it into their local file structure at the right place to facilitate their work.

2) Your statement that development is slowed by having binaries seems like something I would explore further and attempt to measure and quantify.  If you have a clear break between your AppServer and the Clients, then I would expect *no* dependencies between them but instead some proxy code that could be generated by svcutil or some other tool. If this is the case and you are hosting the AppServer in some process and communicating from Clients in another, I don't see why you need to implement your original structure to begin with.  It appears to be unnecessary coupling and I would want to know why it was being done in more detail.